# Create a library when an item on the list is created

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online

I want to create a document library in o365, when an item is created on the list, but i cant get rid of the error: `Unable to get property "apply" of undefined or null reference`. 
Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/ecmascript">

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', spReady);

function spReady (){
    window.onload = Load;

    function Load() {
        var saveButton = document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl34_g_a64d8ee5_2ecd_4e41_badf_2d821f49a109_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem");
        saveButton.onclick = createList;
    }

    function createList() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

        var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
        var ListTitle = document.getElementById("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField").value; // takes the name
        listCreationInfo.set_title(ListTitle); // list name
        listCreationInfo.set_description(ListTitle + 'documents'); // list description
        listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.documentLibrary); //list type

        oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),// when success
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) // when failed
            );
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("List Created");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert("List Failed" + args.get_message());
    }


}

</script>
```

I placed the code in NewForm.aspx, when I click "Save" the library is created, but the item is not and the form isnt closing.

Im a beginner with js so please be patient with my noob questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't remember doing async calls at save before, so not sure its the best solution, but it works:

```
    function createList() {
        this.dfd = $.Deferred();

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

        var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
        var ListTitle = $(":input[title='Title Required Field']").val();  // takes the name
        listCreationInfo.set_title(ListTitle); // list name
        listCreationInfo.set_description(ListTitle + 'documents'); // list description
        listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.documentLibrary); //list type

        oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),// when success
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) // when failed
            );

        return this.dfd.promise();
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("List Created");
        this.dfd.resolve(true);
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert("List Failed" + args.get_message());
        this.dfd.resolve(false);
    }



 function PreSaveAction() { 

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { 
       createList().done(function(val) {
            if(val === true)
            {
                 WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions($('input[id$="diidIOSaveItem"]').attr("Name"), "", true, "", "", false, true));
            }
       });
   });
}
```